# How to alter column with primary key and identity

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to alter column in the existing table for the primary key and identity. I tried below query but showing `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'identity'.`

```
alter table IAM_Software_Licence_Master
alter column SoftwareLicId int  identity(1,1) primary key
```

How can I achieve this..

Comment: You can't ALTER a column. Drop and recreate as per the dupe link

Comment: What is the `CREATE TABLE` definition for the existing table?

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to say what the issues are with changing this on your end as I do not know the table structure or whether or not this is used as a foreign Key. But the below link should give you everything you need:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/04d69ee6-d4f5-4f8f-a115-d89f7bcbc032/how-to-alter-column-to-identity11